# NestJS : return a string

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs

I am using [@nrwl/Nx](https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/getting-started) to create a project.

I successfully add both Angular & Nest projects to it.

I then try to test the connection between the two.

**Angular code**

```js
content;

testEndpoint() {
  this.http.get<any>('api/test').subscribe(res => this.content = res);
}
```

**Nest code**

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('test')
  testConnection(): string {
    return 'Some content';
  }
}
```

As seen, I am simply trying to return a string from the endpoint. In [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers),

> Using this built-in method, when a request handler returns a JavaScript object or array, it will automatically be serialized to JSON. When it returns a string, however, Nest will send just a string without attempting to serialize it. This makes response handling simple: just return the value, and Nest takes care of the rest.

So naturally, I would expect this to work (their exemple is basically the same as this).

But I am met with the following error :

> error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0 at [...]

Even though the HTTP code is 200 and the content can be seen in the network tab.

Could someone explain to me what's the issue ?

(I have tried adding a content type header to the request, but to no success)

**EDIT 1** : the request :

[image]

Comment: Could you check the headers of the response? If client considers it to be JSON (and it's apparently not; JSON-ed string starts from `"` character), either client ignores the mime-type or server still sets it to 'application/json' (or something like that).

Comment: Try changing it to `http.get<string>`, since that's what you're expecting.

Comment: @raina77ow I have uploaded the full request as an image to my question

Comment: @HereticMonkey not working

Comment: @raina77ow the content type header is misleading, but to let you know, after adding `@Header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')` to Nest, it still doesn't work, the header gets removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like HttpClient just ignores the content type sent by server, attempting to always treat the response as JSON. That's weird, but thankfully, you can override it specifying the expected responseType explicitly, as mentioned in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data).

```
this.http.get('api/test', {responseType: 'text'})
```

The caveat is that you'll have to drop the generics part (or erase the type in some other way) because of [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586).

> The generic MUST not be used when `responseType` is specified to something other than `'json'` because `typeof T` will then be inferred automatically.

Comment: This produces `apps/client/src/app/app.component.ts(16,38): error TS2322: Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.`

Comment: From IntelliSense, the only allowed value would be `arraybuffer`

Comment: Overriding with `as any` did the trick though ! 2 minutes to mark it as resolved, thank you for your help !

Comment: Ah, yes. :( There's [the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586) describing the same problem, which is somehow still open. And yes, they mention the similar workaround.

Comment: @raina77ow can you answer my this question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266622/unable-to-create-a-new-project-with-the-nest-cli

Comment: If IntelliSense marks `text` as wrong, remove the `<string>` from `http.get<string>()`.