# Unable to create a new project with the Nest CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs

I am following [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps) tutorial to create a nest project. I have installed **Nest CLI** using this command:

```
npm i -g @nestjs/cli
```

[image]

I have checked the list of packages installed locally using the following command and found that it was successfully installed:

```
npm list -g --depth 0
```

[image]

but when I tried to create a new project using following command it gave me an error:

```
nest new project-name
```

**Error:**

> nest : The term 'nest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
>   path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - nest new project-name
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

> ### Why it is so? What's wrong with it? Can someone assist me in identifying the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to clean npm cache and then install nest again.

Comment: Try to get the latest of node and npm versions as well.

Comment: Try adding alias to your .bash_profile
alias nest="/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/bin/nest"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In most cases, it is better to use `npx` instead of installing global npm packages, since you'll always use the latest version and not clutter your file system with things you don't need often.

Just replace `nest` with `npx @nestjs/cli` for any command:

```
npx @nestjs/cli new project-name
```

Comment: Great! It worked!, can you explain what is the difference b/w use of npx and global packages and why ```nest new project-name
``` did not worked?

Comment: If I had to guess, you may have needed to close and restart your command prompt. I haven't working with Powershell in a long time though, so take tat with a grain of salt :)

Comment: Yup, would have suspected the same. Needs to read in the path again. Npx looks for a locally installed version in your current folder or otherwise installs it but not permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing latest npm using command:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

It worked for me. Also found a related answer here:

https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/223

Comment: Yeah, it works.
After installation on npm I see: `npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.5.0 -> 9.6.2`
so after command `npm install npm@latest -g` nest working without problems!

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of node then `nest new project-name` will work.
If it's not the case then use `npx @nestjs/cli new project-name` instead.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 10, I was able to resolve this by adding npm installation directory to windows `PATH` environment variable.
My npm global installation path was

```
C:\Users\<user.name>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score -1):

For many cases you have to manage environment variables manually. For windows;

1. Right click Start,
2. Click System,
3. Click Advance system settings on the right section under Related settings,
4. System Properties setting will pop up. In Advanced tab, click Environment Variables,
5. In user variables search for path variable. Click edit,
6. Click Browse and find npm folder path (`%AppData%\Roaming\npm`) click add.
7. Close all pop up windows by clicking OK and that's it.
8. Close any opened terminal, PowerShell etc.
9. Open new terminal or PowerShell and type `nest -v` press Enter.
10. If you see the version then everything is fine.